# QOS measurement tool?

Tags: audio, rtp

Can anyone suggest a good audio QOS monitoring tool?
If its a open source one and freely available, it will be great. Its fine otherwise too.

Iam trying to measure QOS for a softphone on a PC and also on a mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link and search for QoS: http://www.slac.stanford.edu/xorg/nmtf/nmtf-tools.html

Bear in mind that a users perception of the quality of a voice call is not an absolute thing so treat any results with this in mind. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESQ for one way (probably the most accepted way) to measure and score voice quality.

You can measure absolutely the delay and packet loss which may give you the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

We have developed a tool for Measuring QoS for both Audio and Video and have some patented algorithms to find out the MOS for Video and used E-model for Audio MOS.

It has been tested on VoIP calls over LTE.

You can check one more tool from EMpirix called Hammer Call analyser or any Elecard tool as well.

But i don't know of any freeware tool in this domain.

Answer (score 0):

I have done voice quality monitoring system for conferencing services provider. Tools used: Empirix Hammer and CallMaster. System in a nutshell: every so often two virtual participants called into conference call. Then each of them spoke a phrase and the other one measured PESQ score. Results were sent to another monitoring system. This worked well. I think PESQ measurement is the way to go for automated testing.